# How to align a set of strings on a character, with a given number of characters on each side (replace missing characters with "x")?

Tags: r, string, alignment

I have a set of strings, each has a single character "X"

```
c("KGDDQSXQGGAPDAGQE", "TEEDSEEVXEQK", "LTXTSGETTQTHTEPTGDSK", "IXTHNSEVEEDDMDK", "SXENPEEDEDQRNPAK", "XTAEHEAAQQDLQSK", "ATVIXHGETLRRTK", "XAVAREESGKPGAHVTVK", "YHTINGHNAEVXK", "XAAEDDEDDDVDTK")
```

I would like to get a character vector with each element having 11 characters, the center of the string is "X" and there is 5 characters from the string on each side. If there are no 5 characters on one of the sides, then "x" is added instead.

E.g.
"KGDDQSXQGGAPDAGQE", becomes "GDDQSXQGGAP"

"TEEDSEEVXEQK", becomes "DSEEVXEQKxx"

"LTXTSGETTQTHTEPTGDSK", becomes "xxxLTXTSGET"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more approach, using stringr:

```r
library(stringr)

vec <- c("KGDDQSXQGGAPDAGQE", "TEEDSEEVXEQK", "LTXTSGETTQTHTEPTGDSK", "IXTHNSEVEEDDMDK", "SXENPEEDEDQRNPAK", "XTAEHEAAQQDLQSK", "ATVIXHGETLRRTK", "XAVAREESGKPGAHVTVK", "YHTINGHNAEVXK", "XAAEDDEDDDVDTK")

vec %>%
  str_pad(width = sapply(vec, nchar) + 10, 
          side = "both", pad = "x") %>%
  str_match(".{5}X.{5}")
#>       [,1]         
#>  [1,] "GDDQSXQGGAP"
#>  [2,] "DSEEVXEQKxx"
#>  [3,] "xxxLTXTSGET"
#>  [4,] "xxxxIXTHNSE"
#>  [5,] "xxxxSXENPEE"
#>  [6,] "xxxxxXTAEHE"
#>  [7,] "xATVIXHGETL"
#>  [8,] "xxxxxXAVARE"
#>  [9,] "HNAEVXKxxxx"
#> [10,] "xxxxxXAAEDD"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, character must contain `"X"`.

1. `strsplit` with `X`. Now have two separated strings. call them `Left`, `Right`
2. If `Left` has length shorter than `5`, add `x`. same for `Right`
3. Else if `Left` has length longer than `5`, select only `5` characters. same for `Right`
4. `paste` them.

```
vec <- c("KGDDQSXQGGAPDAGQE", "TEEDSEEVXEQK", 
"LTXTSGETTQTHTEPTGDSK", "IXTHNSEVEEDDMDK", 
"SXENPEEDEDQRNPAK", "XTAEHEAAQQDLQSK", 
"ATVIXHGETLRRTK", "XAVAREESGKPGAHVTVK", 
"YHTINGHNAEVXK", "XAAEDDEDDDVDTK")

myf <- function(v){

  v <- unlist(strsplit(v,'X'))
  Left <- v[1]
  Right <- v[2]

  if(nchar(Left)>5){
    Left <- substr(Left, nchar(Left)-4 ,nchar(Left))
  }
  else{
    Left <- paste0(paste0(rep('x', 5-nchar(Left)),collapse = ''), Left, collapse = '')
  }

  if(nchar(Right)>5){
    Right <- substr(Right, 1, 5)
  }
  else{
    Right <- paste0(Right, paste0(rep('x', 5-nchar(Right)), collapse = '') , collapse = '')
  }

  paste0(Left,'X',Right,collapse = '')
}


sapply(vec, myf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option

```
charcenter <- function(input, char="X", pad=5) {
  index <- regexpr("X", input, fixed=TRUE)
  extr <- substr(input, pmax(0, index-pad), pmin(index+pad, nchar(input)))
  padl <- strrep("x", pmax(pad-index+1, 0))
  padr <- strrep("x", pmax(pad-nchar(input)+index, 0))
  paste0(padl, extr, padr)
}
```

we use the regular expression to find the first X, then use `substr()` to extract as much as we can around it, and then find out how much padding is needed and each side and add that in.

If I combine it with the input, Here's the result

```
input <- c("KGDDQSXQGGAPDAGQE", "TEEDSEEVXEQK", "LTXTSGETTQTHTEPTGDSK", "IXTHNSEVEEDDMDK", "SXENPEEDEDQRNPAK", "XTAEHEAAQQDLQSK", "ATVIXHGETLRRTK", "XAVAREESGKPGAHVTVK", "YHTINGHNAEVXK", "XAAEDDEDDDVDTK")
cbind(charcenter(input), input)
#                     input                 
#  [1,] "GDDQSXQGGAP" "KGDDQSXQGGAPDAGQE"   
#  [2,] "DSEEVXEQKxx" "TEEDSEEVXEQK"        
#  [3,] "xxxLTXTSGET" "LTXTSGETTQTHTEPTGDSK"
#  [4,] "xxxxIXTHNSE" "IXTHNSEVEEDDMDK"     
#  [5,] "xxxxSXENPEE" "SXENPEEDEDQRNPAK"    
#  [6,] "xxxxxXTAEHE" "XTAEHEAAQQDLQSK"     
#  [7,] "xATVIXHGETL" "ATVIXHGETLRRTK"      
#  [8,] "xxxxxXAVARE" "XAVAREESGKPGAHVTVK"  
#  [9,] "HNAEVXKxxxx" "YHTINGHNAEVXK"       
# [10,] "xxxxxXAAEDD" "XAAEDDEDDDVDTK"
```